# Comparing sqlite query result to delete found value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am running a query in SQLite to check to see if the value of a variable is in a specific column, if it not found than it gives a messagebox stating the variable value is not in the column. I am having trouble with the second part of my code where it will deleting a row if the variable value is found in the column.

I am using an if and else statement and using the comparison expression != (not equal) and == (equal). I am sure what I am overlooking is something small but it's late and I'm foggy at this point.

The code:

```
try:
    checkInput = Recipe.get()
    c.execute('SELECT Recipe FROM Recipes WHERE Recipe = :checkInput',{"checkInput": checkInput})
    conn.commit()
    theResult = c.fetchall()
        if theResult!= checkInput:
        messagebox.showinfo("Recipes","That recipe name does not exist in the database.")
        recipe_entry.delete(0,END)
    else:
        c.execute('DELETE FROM Recipes WHERE Recipe =:checkInput',{"checkInput": checkInput})
        conn.commit()
        messagebox.showinfo("Recipes","The recipe was deleted successfully.")
        recipe_entry.delete(0,END)
except:
    messagebox.showerror("Recipes","Database Error.")
```

The initial query works fine and it will throw the messagebox if the variable value is not found in the query. And if I comment out the query part of the code then the DELETE works fine. What I am not seeing is why the if and else statements are not working properly so if the variable value is not there... messagebox to say that and if it is there it deletes the row.

I am clearly overlooking something here.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this issue after getting some rest.

The issue was the comparison:

```
if theResult != checkInput:
```

I needed to change it to:

```
if theResult == None:
```

This small oversight is resolved and working as it should.